# Reactstrap - The return type of e when using Input of type "select"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

When using the  tag imported from reactstrap, I came across a minor problem.
I used

```
<.Input type="select" ... /.>

and wrapped inside it

 <.option value={}....>
```

so that when an option was selected, the value of the input was set to the value of the selected option.

Even when the value of the Input tag was set with a number, accessing `e.target.value` provided me with a string, which I had to parse into an `int`.

So I was wondering if there is a specific return type for the Input tag of type select in reactstrap- even when the value is inputted as a number, does it automatically save it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a way to achieve this in `reactstrap`. However the beauty of React is that you are able to quickly write your own reusable component to achieve this.

```
const NumberSelect = (props) => (
  <input type='select' onChange={(event) => {
    props.onChange(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
  }}>
    <option value={1}>One</option>
    <option value={2}>Two</option>
  </input>
);
```

You will need to tweak this code a bit according your own needs, but this is how I would solve your problem.

Comment: I don't really mind that it returns a string, as I can just parse the value into an int. I was just wondering about the property of the Input tag in reactstrap- if it has a fixed return type of string, and if it was structured so by design. So my current understanding according to your answer is that it DOES save the inputted value as a string, am I correct? 
Thanks for the answer though, I appreciate it :)

Comment: It does most likely save it as a string somehow. However when using the native `<select>` in React this is _not_ the case, `e.target.value` would be of type `String` or `Number` depending on the value of the `<option>` tag.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the clarification!